# How to programmatically resume a paused print in Marlin

Tags: marlin

A print that is paused with an `M0` can be unpaused with `M108`.
That works with my Chiron running Marlin 2.0.7.2.
However, it also has a display that uses its' own serial protocol to communicate with Marlin. I want that display to be able to unpause my printer when it has encountered `M0` in the G-code.
I tried `injectCommands_P(PSTR("M108\n"));` in the code, but it did not work. Perhaps I should not have a new-line at the end of it.

What is the correct command to do this?

```
void GcodeSuite::M108() {
  TERN_(HAS_RESUME_CONTINUE, wait_for_user = false);
  wait_for_heatup = false;
}
```

Above is the Marlin code for `M108`. Would be great if someone could decipher what TERN means.

Comment: TERN is short for "Ternary Macro". [Scroll down on this web page to find what it is used for](https://marlinfw.org/docs/development/coding_standards.html). Basically, this is an if-then statement.

Comment: under pause, the next line of G-code isn't read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Marlin-command to unpause seems to be `setUserConfirmed()`. I have tested that it works.